# r.resolveMx is not a function

Tags: javascript, forms, npm

I'm trying to use [sendMail.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sendmail)

here the code on form submit:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        var message = $('#message');
        var name = $('#name');
        var contacts = $('#contacts')
        var messageVal = 'Name: '+name+'<br>Contacts: '+contacts+'<br>Message: '+message;
sendmail({
            from: 'contact@mydomain.com',
            to: 'myemail@gmail.com ',
            subject: 'test sendmail',
            content: 'Mail of test sendmail ',
          }, function(err, reply) {
            console.log(err && err.stack);
            console.dir(reply);
        });
      return false;
     });
});
```

I'm getting an error `dns.resolveMx is not a function` on form submit. 
Why it happens?

Comment: Are you doing this on NodeJS ?

Comment: i use NodeJS and browserify